# How to pass a geolocation variable from client to server side

Tags: javascript, django, html, google-maps, geolocation

Can someone please suggest me a method to pass a client side Java Script location variable (lat,lng) to my server side as soon as the user allows for his geolocation to be used. So that I can use the location variable to query my database for stores within a range of 10 km and display them on a map.

I am using [HTML5 Geolocation](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp) on the client side for obtaining user's location and Django + PostGIS database on the server side for carrying out the distance lookups.

Comment: How do you pass any other data from client to server?  Why would geolocation data be any different?

Comment: One way you can do is to store the geolocation in client browser cookie and fetch it in server side using `request.COOKIES.get('cookie_name')`

Comment: @robertc the situation that I am in is slightly different, I am trying to pass the location data to the server immediately after the user allows for his geolocation to be used (as you may know this prompt is built into HTML5) and without having the user to submit his geolocation by clicking an additional button. Please click on [this link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation) to see the prompt. Hope its clear.

Comment: Have you heard of Ajax?

Comment: I've tried using Jquery's Post method, but I wasn't successful in sending the position variable(pos). Below is the code I am using, the url directs to function on the server, which requests for a pos variable. `$(document).ready(function()$.post("/location",pos))`

Comment: You're not going to have the co-ords on `$(document).ready`, it will take time for the user to accept the request for geolocation information and the browser to derive the position (lock on to satellites etc.), you need to do the post in the success callback of `getCurrentPosition()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inorder to pass the user Geolocation from client side to server side as soon as the user allows for his Geolocation to be used, is by

1. Assigning user position variable (pos) to a HTML element (location)
2. Then, auto submitting a HTML form that contains a POST method.

Both the above codes have to be written within Google Geolocation API, as shown below in the excerpt.

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    map: map,
    position: pos,
    content: 'Location found using HTML5.'
  });
  // the below line has been inserted to assign a JS variable to HTML input field called 'geolocation'
document.getElementById('location').value = pos
  map.setCenter(pos);
// the below line has been inserted to autosubmit the form.  
document.getElementById("geolocation").submit();
```

Below is the HTML form

```
<form id = "geolocation" action="/location" method="POST" >
            {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="text" id = "location" name="location" value="" />
        <input type="submit" />

</form>
```